# SSRS: Conditional available values with additional custom input

Tags: reporting-services

These were the requirements given for an SSRS report:

1. A dropdown for quickly changing dates to preset ranges, such as
   "YTD" or "Last 12 months"
2. The selected option in the dropdown should be stored in the database for each user, and retrieved when opening the report
3. The dates should be able to be edited directly despite what has been selected

The issue is that parameters don't cascade their default values without refreshing, requiring the report to be re-run to take effect and store the option, then to be refreshed to actually populate the "Default Values" for the date. This can be fixed by using "Available Values" instead, but means that the date fields will no longer be editable.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem easy to some, but it stumped me for a bit. This is the solution that now works.

The parameters that need to be used are RangeOption, StartDate, EndDate, StartDateCustomInput, EndDateCustomInput

First, we need to create a table in the database to store the user's report preferences. SSRS has a built-in field for the user ID, so this can be passed to remember what the user's last "Range Option" was.

[image]

We follow this up by creating two stored procedures, one that gets the last run option for the user, and one that sets it. The SSRS username is the built-in user ID field.

[image]

The setting procedure should be put into a dataset, which will refresh and store the "Range Option" when the dropdown option is selected.

[image]

The dropdown parameter will use the getter procedure as its "Default Value". Under Advanced, make sure this is set to "**Never Refresh**".

[image]

To get the dates to update automatically without the need to re-run the report and refresh, we need to use "Available Values" instead. Plug in whatever expression you want to use, which references the dropdown parameter (@RangeOption) The catch is that this makes the date unable to be edited.

[image]

To make the date editable, a **second** date parameter needs to be created for our start and end dates. These dates will use "Default Values" that simply grab whatever is in the original start and end date parameters. Then, point all of our report items to the editable date fields (@StartDateCustomInput,@EndDateCustomInput).

[image]

Now, the dropdown alters the original date parameters, which then alter the editable date parameters, without running the report. The editable parameters can be altered first if the user wants, and the report will run with whatever is in these custom date parameters. *The downside is that the original date parameters do not seem to cascade if they are hidden/internal, so you will likely need to have duplicate visible date parameters.*

For some reason, the default values for the date parameters cascade in this way, but not the original approach.